# Matrix Inverse Code(c, c++, fortran or tksolver)

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I need a code to determine the inverse of an nxn matrix A using row operations.
I am having a ridiculous time writing this code. Anything helps, I am a grad student and havent taken a programming class in years. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming you have been asked to write the inverter (rather than just needing to use one from a library) the first question is: can you perform the inversion by hand? If so, try coding the procedure, and then tell us *where you get stuck*...

Comment: I need the code for a project

Comment: the inversion needs to be coded for nxn matrices, hence the problem

Comment: Not a problem - get a good library.  You need not code it - unless that's the assignment.  If that's true, get busy.

Answer (score 2):

You might not really want the inverse.  If you're trying to solve a system of equations you'd be better off using LU decomposition.

You don't say what language you'd like to write this app in.  Java has Apache Commons Math; Python has NumPy; FORTRAN has LinPack.  Pick a language and use a library; don't write it yourself.

Comment: Exactly, see http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/ for more. Though, given this is a homework question, he is probably asked for the inverse.

Answer (score 2):

```
  SUBROUTINE MATINV(A,N)
  DIMENSION A(N,N)
  DO 1 I=1,N
     Z=A(I,I)
     A(I,I)=1.0
     DO 2 J=1,N
2       A(I,J)=A(1,J)/Z
     DO 1 K=1,N
        IF (K-I) 3,1,3
3          Z=A(K,I)
        A(K,I)=0.0
        DO 4 J=1,N
4          A(K,J)=A(K,J)-Z*A(I,J)
1 CONTINUE
  RETURN
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org/) or MATLAB for matrix operations if you haven't taken a programming class in years.

If it is a one time calculation, look at WolframAlpha.

If using libraries is an option for C++, look at [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Ideally i would use mathematica but these are the only programs allowed for the code:
c
c++
fortran
tksolver

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Numerical Recipies Online](http://www.nrbook.com/a/). The Fortran 77, Ansi C and Fortran 90 code is free and you can get pleanty of clues on how to best proceed.